# when clicking a button it deletes everything

Tags: javascript, html

note new to JavaScript

when clicking the button to write out the text from my input box it prints out the text but deletes everything else

JavaScript code

```
let = Text
document.getElementById("Button7").onclick = function () {
    Text = document.getElementById("myText").value;


    
    document.write(Text)

}
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="enter text"> <br>
    <button id="Button7">enter</button>
    



    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<h1>my first website test</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that when initialising a variable in JavaScript, you shouldn't use the equals sign with `let`.

Comment: @BestCoderBoy Not only is it not necessary, but it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: There is a syntax with the let statement: `let = Text` should be `let Text = "lorum ipsum or whatever the text is to show on page"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the value of the input in a `<p>` element by setting its `textContent`. Do not use `document.write`.

```js
document.getElementById("Button7").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = document.getElementById("myText").value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="enter text"> <br>
<button id="Button7">enter</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```